# Modx FormIt, got 2 forms, formit send both

Tags: forms, modx, formit

**This is my code, I can't understand why formit sends both the forms. It means I have 2 messages instead of one.**

I use two templates and different `&prefix`:

```
[[!FormIt?
    &hooks=`spam,email,emailUser`
    &emailTo=`sitename@gmail.com`
    &emailFromName=`[[+name]]`
    &emailTpl=`ContactTpl`
    &prefix="fi"
]]
<div>[[+fi.error.error_message]]</div>

        <form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" id="recall">
        <input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="" />
          <input type="text" name="name" class="right" id="recall_name" required="required" value="[[+fi.name]]">
          <input type="number" name="number" class="right" id="recall_number"value="[[+fi.number]]" >
          <textarea name="message:required:stripTags" value="[[+fi.message]]"></textarea>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
[[!FormItRetriever]]
[[!FormIt?
    &hooks=`spam,email,emailUser`
    &emailTo=`sitename@gmail.com`
    &prefix="cs"
    &emailFromName=`[[+sup_name]]`
    &emailTpl=`SupportTpl`
]]
<div>[[+fi.error.error_message]]</div>
        <form action="[[~[[*id]]]]" method="post" id="support">
        <input type="hidden" name="nospam:blank" value="" />
          <label for="name" class="right" >Имя:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" class="right" id="support_name" required="required" value="[[+cs.sup_name]]">
          <input type="number" name="number" value="[[+cs.sup_number]]">
          <textarea name="message:required:stripTags"value="[[+cs.sup_message]]"></textarea>
          <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the submitVar attribute: http://rtfm.modx.com/extras/revo/formit

your formit calls don't know which form they should be submitting. Set a name on each form submit control and set the submitVar for each in your formit calls.